# Energy saving in Windows doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, energy-saving

I have problems with the energy saving in Windows 10.

`powercfg.exe /request` doesn't show a problem.

`powercfg.exe /devicequery` doesn't list a device (I removed all).

I removed the energy saving plan and re-created it with defaults.

Where can I found a forum, to get assistance?

[Power settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJuDR.png)

[Power report](https://nils-weg.de/energy-report.html)

... unfortunately, this is a German windows. :-(

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a screen shot of your energy savings settings.  Mostly, when the battery gets low in my machines, the screen dims until it is plugged in. Otherwise the laptop uses the energy it needs.

Comment: Create and post a [powercfg -energy report](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5148-create-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: You do not have the display turning off. I turn the Display OFF after 5 minutes on battery and 15 minutes on AC. Screen ON is one of the biggest drains on battery, so do that and see if the screen turns off.

Comment: The report indicates that there are some problems with the whole USB subsystem. Which drivers are installed for the USB chip (I assume it is integrated in the Intel PCH)? The standard from Microsoft, those from Intel or does Apple provide them for Windows on Mac?

Comment: @Robert: Yes, there are a lot of problems. But there is also mentioned: "This problem does not prevent not the into the standby modus."